# gcc4.5 on redhat enterprise 3 wield asm warning message

Tags: c, gcc, assembly, gcc-warning

I compiled gcc 4.5.2 on a 64bit Redhat enterprise 3 machine (2.4.21-20.ELsmp, glibc 2.3.2). It compiles ok but with a lot of warning message like

```
/tmp/ccbGRF5F.s: Assembler messages:
/tmp/ccbGRF5F.s:29: Warning: rest of line ignored; first ignored character is `d'
/tmp/ccbGRF5F.s:33: Warning: rest of line ignored; first ignored character is `d'
/tmp/ccbGRF5F.s:169: Warning: rest of line ignored; first ignored character is `i'
```

Then I try to compile code with the compiler, still it spits these asm warnings, and I'm not using any asm in my C code. How can I get rid of it? Fix or suppress warning are all fine.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It seems your binutils is too old to handle gcc-4.5's output - and in another project it might outright end in a compile failure. Given RHEL3, that would not surprise me at all.

Comment: "compile failure": actually, it could be much worse: this might end in silent generation of incorrect code...

Comment: I migrate to RHEL4, and it goes away. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming you're using the command line to compile? adding a "-w" flag to the compile command will suppress all warnings. For example, to compile hello.c without warnings:

```
 gcc hello.c -w -o hello
```

Will produce the output file "hello", without spitting out any errors.